# Permission denied error with phantomjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

I am using Rails 4.0.2, Guard 2.2.4, guard-rspec 4.2.4, rspec-rails 2.14.0, Capybara 2.2.1 and Poltergeist 1.5.0 on Ruby 2.0.0-p353 and OSX Mavericks.

When I run bundle exec guard I got a lot of failure with this error message : 
An error occurred in an after hook
  Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs
  occurred at /Users/gillesmath/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open3.rb:211:in `spawn'

I checked the permission on /usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs and didn't notice  anything unusual. I can run phantomjs without 'sudo'.

My spec_helper file look like this :
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", **FILE**)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require "capybara/rspec"
require 'webmock/rspec'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

WebMock.disable_net_connect!(:net_http_connect_on_start => true, :allow_localhost => true)

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist

I can't see what is wrong because the owner:group is the same for both the rails app and the /usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs dir and its content.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error makes it look like it's trying to execute the `/usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs` *directory* instead of the executable inside it. I think Poltergeist scans your `PATH` for the first thing called `phantomjs`. Is `/usr/local/Cellar` in your `PATH`?

If so, I'd recommend taking it out, since executables should never appear in there directly.

If you can't, another option is to configure Poltergeist with an explicit path to `phantomjs` in your setup code: https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist#customization

It looks like someone has already [opened a pull request with a fix to skip directories](https://github.com/yaauie/cliver/pull/12) in the [Cliver](https://github.com/yaauie/cliver) gem that Poltergeist uses, so hopefully that will be fixed soon!