# Running tests from staging server rails phantomjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, integration-testing, phantomjs, poltergeist

I have a rails app when I have setup a admin testing UI so our testing team can enter criteria and run the dynamic criteria through a test suite.

I have a cron job that checks for queued tests waiting to be run and then runs them one at a time through capybara and poltergeist/phantomjs

This works on my local development machine in dev environment but when I deploy it to staging environment on our remote server it doesn't find any assets i.e. js, css and images.

Looking at the source it looks like its trying to get them from `http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets` which is the issue.

I have tried changing the asset_host to be the same as staging environment but didn't seem to change it.

Can anyone help with this ?

Here is my test.rb env file

```
MyApp::Application.configure do

  config.session_store :redis_store, :key => 'staging'

  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
  # test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
  # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
  # and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil
  #config.whiny_nils = true

  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection    = false

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr

  config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://dev1.domain.com/staging"
end
```

Comment: Can you be a little clearer about your architecture? When you deploy your app to staging, are you deploying the app with RAILS_ENV=production but running your cron job with RAILS_ENV=test, or something else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045997/permission-denied-error-with-phantomjs related?